# Changing the CSS with a plugin

Tags: plugins, customization, css, options, wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to make a plugin that changes the CSS file. My client want to change the colors each season, and we want to make it foolproof so they won't break anything.

I've managed to create the option page but I can't seem to get the actual function to work.

```
<?php
class SeizoensKleuren {
    private $seizoens_kleuren_options;

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'seizoens_kleuren_add_plugin_page' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'seizoens_kleuren_page_init' ) );
    }

    public function seizoens_kleuren_add_plugin_page() {
        add_menu_page(
            'Seizoens kleuren', // page_title
            'Seizoens kleuren', // menu_title
            'manage_options', // capability
            'seizoens-kleuren', // menu_slug
            array( $this, 'seizoens_kleuren_create_admin_page' ), // function
            'dashicons-admin-appearance', // icon_url
            81 // position
        );
    }

    public function seizoens_kleuren_create_admin_page() {
        $this->seizoens_kleuren_options = get_option( 'seizoens_kleuren_option_name' ); ?>

        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>Seizoens kleuren</h2>
            <p>Verander hier de kleuren van de site n.a.v. het seizoen!</p>
            <?php settings_errors(); ?>

            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                <?php
                    settings_fields( 'seizoens_kleuren_option_group' );
                    do_settings_sections( 'seizoens-kleuren-admin' );
                    submit_button();
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php }

    public function seizoens_kleuren_page_init() {
        register_setting(
            'seizoens_kleuren_option_group', // option_group
            'seizoens_kleuren_option_name', // option_name
            array( $this, 'seizoens_kleuren_sanitize' ) // sanitize_callback
        );

        add_settings_section(
            'seizoens_kleuren_setting_section', // id
            'Settings', // title
            array( $this, 'seizoens_kleuren_section_info' ), // callback
            'seizoens-kleuren-admin' // page
        );

        add_settings_field(
            'seizoen_0', // id
            'Seizoen:', // title
            array( $this, 'seizoen_0_callback' ), // callback
            'seizoens-kleuren-admin', // page
            'seizoens_kleuren_setting_section' // section
        );
    }

    public function seizoens_kleuren_sanitize($input) {
        $sanitary_values = array();
        if ( isset( $input['seizoen_0'] ) ) {
            $sanitary_values['seizoen_0'] = $input['seizoen_0'];
        }

        return $sanitary_values;
    }

    public function seizoens_kleuren_section_info() {
        
    }

    public function seizoen_0_callback() {
        ?> <select name="seizoens_kleuren_option_name[seizoen_0]" id="seizoen_0">
            <?php $selected = (isset( $this->seizoens_kleuren_options['seizoen_0'] ) && $this->seizoens_kleuren_options['seizoen_0'] === 'lente') ? 'selected' : '' ; ?>
            <option value="lente" <?php echo $selected; ?>>Lente</option>
            <?php $selected = (isset( $this->seizoens_kleuren_options['seizoen_0'] ) && $this->seizoens_kleuren_options['seizoen_0'] === 'zomer') ? 'selected' : '' ; ?>
            <option value="zomer" <?php echo $selected; ?>>Zomer</option>
            <?php $selected = (isset( $this->seizoens_kleuren_options['seizoen_0'] ) && $this->seizoens_kleuren_options['seizoen_0'] === 'herfst') ? 'selected' : '' ; ?>
            <option value="herfst" <?php echo $selected; ?>>Herfst</option>
            <?php $selected = (isset( $this->seizoens_kleuren_options['seizoen_0'] ) && $this->seizoens_kleuren_options['seizoen_0'] === 'winter') ? 'selected' : '' ; ?>
            <option value="winter" <?php echo $selected; ?>>Winter</option>
        </select> <?php
    }

}
if ( is_admin() )
    $seizoens_kleuren = new SeizoensKleuren();

/* 
 * Retrieve this value with:
 * $seizoens_kleuren_options = get_option( 'seizoens_kleuren_option_name' ); // Array of All Options
 * $seizoen_0 = $seizoens_kleuren_options['seizoen_0']; // Seizoen:
 */

function seizoenplugin_enqueue_styles() 
{
    // Get the user's stylesheet choice from the options, default to "lente"
    $seizoens_kleuren_options = get_option( 'lente');

    // Conditionally load the appropriate stylesheet
    if( $seizoens_kleuren_options == 'lente' ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'seizoenplugin-lente', plugins_url( '/css/lente.css', __FILE__ ) );
    } elseif( $seizoens_kleuren_options == 'zomer') {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'seizoenplugin-zomer', plugins_url( '/css/zomer.css', __FILE__ ) );
    } elseif( $seizoens_kleuren_options == 'herfst') {
      wp_enqueue_style( 'seizoenplugin-herfst', plugins_url( '/css/herfst.css', __FILE__ ) );
    } elseif( $seizoens_kleuren_options == 'winter') {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'seizoenplugin-winter', plugins_url( '/css/winter.css', __FILE__ ) );
  }
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'seizoenplugin_enqueue_styles' );

  
  ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :).
Cheers!

Comment: There’s a lot of code there. What, specifically, isn’t working?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Hi, thanks for reaching out! It's the last function: seizoenplugin_enqueue_styles. It doesn't do anything, I select the option 'Zomer' on my settings page but it doesn't enqueue the CSS located at /css/zomer.css

Comment: Are you trying to load the stylesheets in the admin?

Comment: No, I'm trying to load them in the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong hook to enqueue your styles:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'seizoenplugin_enqueue_styles' );
```

As the name suggests, `admin_enqueue_scripts` is for enqueuing scripts and styles in the admin. To enqueue scripts on the front end use `wp_enqueue_scripts`:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'seizoenplugin_enqueue_styles' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't fix my problem. It still doesn't update my CSS on the front-end.

Comment: I has to be wp_enqueue_style() .. not _script.

Comment: @Fredrik Thank you, still doesn't load my CSS files though...